# Angular2 fire click event on unknown html element

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to handle a click event of x3dom's `shape` html element in my parent component. **The `onclick` event is fired by x3dom**. I can only delegate it with an ugly hack (see below).
Because `shape` is not a known Html tag by Angular 2 I have to define a`shape` component? or Not?

In Parent Component:

```
<shape (click)="doStuffInParent()" ></shape> <!-- click is not fired by x3dom -->
```

Shape component so far:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'Shape',
  providers: [],
  directives: [],
  pipes: []
})
export class Shape {
    @Output() notify: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>(); // wrong!

  constructor() {}

}
```

Edit: Maybe I don't need the component? The onclick event is fired by X3dom and not by me.

another solution for me would be if I can just call my component method from a regular `onclick` event what I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717256/call-angular-2-component-method-from-html-event?noredirect=1#comment64810730_38717256).

Update **I hacked a solution what solved at least my problem:**

[call Angular 2 component method from html event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717256/call-angular-2-component-method-from-html-event/38720385#38720385)

Comment: So you have a function in your shape component that you want to have access to it from a parent component which is using shape ?

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/qQudgi9touIFOe52m4JY?p=preview

```
<Shape (myClick)="doStuffInParent($event)"></Shape>
```

in Component code,

```
doStuffInParent(value){
  console.log(value); //Angular2
}
```

---

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'Shape',
  providers: [],
  directives: [],
  pipes: [],
  template:`<div (click)="click()">Shap Component</div>`
})


export class Shape { 
    @Output() myClick: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>(); 

    click(){
       this.myClick.next('Angular2');
    }

  }
```

Comment: does not fire and all children from shape inside parent component are removed

Comment: all children are removed from  `shape`. The `onclick` is fired by x3dom. This can't work?!

Comment: thanks, but I have no div inside my shape component. The onclick event is fired by x3dom

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of x3dom.