# call Angular 2 component method from html event

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to call an angular component method from a html event?

```
<shape onclick="myMethodInParentComponent()" >
```

I can't use `(click)` because `shape` is not known by angular. Shape has also many unknown sub elements so that rebuilding the whole DOM-Tree into Comoponents is too much work for me.

Comment: Instead of asking a new question it would be better to improve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716878/angular2-fire-click-event-on-unknown-html-element which seems to be quite similar.

Comment: this is another question. Here I ask how I can handle the angular2 method with regular onlick event and in the other question it's the other way around.

Comment: `(click)` is a regular click event. `onclick` is pure JS and not related to Angular2.

Comment: and this is my problem. X3dom does fire `onclick` events and not angular's `(click)`

Comment: There is no `onclick` event. Mouse clicks fire `click` events and `onclick` is the event handler that is called when a `click` handler is fired. From Angular2 you can register your own event handler for the `click` event by using `(click)="handler($event)"` instead of `onclick="handler"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hack but what I asked for was a hack:

```ts
onclick="ng.probe(myparendcomponentid).componentInstance.mymethod()
```

Comment: Are you sure this still works when switched to prodMode?

Comment: No this is only for debugging purposes and therefore only in devMode. If you could provide more information about what exactly you try to accomplish then it would be easier to provide proper solutions. That's the first time I hear someone has issues with a click event. That's the most basic thing at all. The only thing that can cause issues is when the element is added dynamically using `element.append()` or `[innerHTML]="someHtml"`. Besides that it just works. If it doesn't for you , you're doing something weird. Can you create a plunker and post it to the other question?

Comment: Hard to believe. If it really works, it's till an ugly hack because `ng...` is not supposed to be used except for debugging purposes. I assume you're setting `prodMode` to late where it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I set it before `bootstrap`. Also the angular message how to enable prodmode is not printed to console. I know it`s an ugly hack.

Comment: Then it looks like I'm wrong about `ng...` not working in prodMode.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom directive with **HostListener** implemented.[Listen click event using directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostListener-var.html)

Use event emitter to call a function in parent component